# How to access nth element of array within loop in macro SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get the ith  item of an array within %do loop in macro definition and create a dataset with the name of the element, but all I can get is something like "z1" etc. This is what I got so far

```
%macro print(set,groupvar);
  proc sql ;
  select put(count(distinct &groupvar),1.)
 into :hm
 from &set
 ;


  select distinct set
  into :z1-:z&sysmaxlong
  from &set
  ;
    quit;

  data %do i =1 %to &hm;
        %scan(&z, &i);
       %end;
    ;
%mend;
```

I also tried z[&i] instead of `%scan(&z,&i)` but still no luck

Comment: What's happening with this that makes you feel unlucky?

Comment: It creates only one dataset named "z" instead of three datasets which I want to create using the values from column "set"

Comment: Google ‘sas split data into subsets’ and you’ll find a ton of examples if that’s what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. You have a macro variable SET but you have the distinct SET in the select query, is that what you intended?

   ```
   select distinct set
   ```
2. You don't need to specify the end of a series when creating macro variables.

   ```
   select distinct &set into :z1- from &set; quit;
   ```
3. You created a series of macro variables Z1-Zn but try and use SCAN to retrieve the values? They're not stored in an array, its stored in a series of macro variables such as Z1, Z2 etc.

Comment: Thanks for response! 1: yes, this was intended, I called the first parameter "set" but this is also a name of the column where the names of the sets are stored, my mistsake. 3: thank for clarification, I am only starting with everything, so I still may misunderstand some things. If they are variables, then will it be enough to access them with symget() or in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

An `output` statement **can not** specify a dynamic destination table. You will need to create wallpaper code to output to the appropriate table based on splitting criteria.

Your macro will need to create macro variables to support this code template

```
data &out1 &out2 … &outN;
  set input_data;
  select;
    when (&case1) output &out1;
    when (&case2) output &out2;
    …
    when (&caseN) output &outN;
    otherwise;
  end;
run;
```

Some slick SQL could support the template

```
data &outlist;
  set input_data;
  select;
    &whenStatements;
    otherwise;
  end;
run;
```

The hash object .output() method can specify a dynamic destination for saving hash contents.  Consider the case of "Split a table into subset tables whose names are based on a variables values" aka "Split one data set into several data sets named according to a group variable". Some methods require a pre-parse of the data (as in your posted code), others do not.

There is some hash based splitter code at https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/hash-6.sas

You can find other data splitters on sas community.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `%scan()` then just create **one** macro variable.

```
select distinct set
   into :z separated by ' '
   from &set
;
%let hm=&sqlobs;
```

The `DATA` statement will end at the first semi-colon.  But you are generating `&hm+1` semi-colons instead of just one.  Remove the spurious semi-colon from inside the `%do` loop.

```
data
%do i =1 %to &hm;
  %scan(&z, &i)
%end;
;
```